# Is there any tool to get the original query from linq in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio

I searched for the above title many times and I cannot match any tool in visual studio 2012 that can get the original query from linq , I tried Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll and others but not working

Answer (score 0):

What I generally do when I need to see the SQL generated, I put a breakpoint on the LINQ line, hover over LINQ expression and copy it.

Comment: ok that will get the linq and i need the original sql statement